# Check MySql record without refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for my English.

I have PHP/MySql page. So, when page is opened php check row in MySql database, where one column show when row status is „loading”, and in html user see „Record is loading now”. How can I check record status without refreshing page? For example, is oppened page with message „Record is loading now”, and when another process change value in MySql, message disapears, automaticly, without refreshing page.

Comment: I think you are searching for AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use Ajax. This solution uses jQuery ajax. We have one .php page that fetches the information, then a html page for display.

```
myphp.php
<?php
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable") or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo $data['load_status'];

    mysql_free_result($res);

?>

myhtml.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="load_status"></p>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(function()
{
   $.ajax({url:"myphp.php", type:"GET", async:true, cache:false, success:function(result)
{
     $("#load_status").html(result);
}});

},1000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above demonstration will update the load status every one second. You'll need to download jquery from jquery.com, then include it into your html page via the src attribute of the script tag. This technique of refreshing the content of a page without page reload, if you never knew, is called ajax.

All the best bro

Answer (score 0):

You need to add javascript to the page. Use setTimeout to poll the server (php) at an interval, making ajax requests that retrieve new data. You can send your php script the current values so it only has to output when there is new data.

I find it easiest for the php script to send actual HTML so you only have to replace the contents of a div. You may want to use jQuery to simplify your ajax requests, and modifying the page. But get a simple ajax request to your server working first.